# How should I frame around a basement window to allow for drywall finishing?

Tags: drywall, basement, framing

I am working to finish my basement and starting to frame around the windows. The windows in my basement just have some vinyl returns on them and are installed flush with the concrete foundation walls. I would like to box (wrap?) these when we get to drywall without any trim.

When I do my framing—do I frame right up flush to the window so that the drywall can be installed on top of the vinyl returns with an L bead and be completely seamless with the drywall

or...

Do do I leave 1/2 inch gap round for the thickness of the drywall and try to but it up to the existing vinyl return somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just frame up flush, as you suggested, and let the cornerbead (your "L bead") die into the window.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you! That is definitely the routing I was leaning towards.

Comment: @nspace, we show gratitude with votes and answer accepts on SE. Please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour).